# Statistic help relating to exercise and deaths

Tags: correlation

Hi I'm trying to make a correlation between exercise and death for my group project but I'm not sure how to do it.

If there are 320,970,000 people in the United States and about 250,000 people die every year for not exercising, how do I correlate that information with my class of 31 students.  So in other words, using the information about US deaths a year, how many students in my class of 31 (theoretically) would die due to not exercising?
Is the margin between people in the US and the amount of people that die a year so big that I could basically say to my class "1 out of 31 of you will die due to not exercising"? Or is the statistic even less than 1 out of 31 students?

I know there are many other factors that contribute to the deaths but this is just a simple group project (for my speech class) so I don't have to be very accurate, just close enough. Thank you

Comment: I think you can treat how many of your 31 people will die due to not exercising as a binomial distribution. And you already have the parameter $p_0$ whis is 250,000/320,970,000.

Comment: (250000/320,970,000 = x/31 ) = .02 ; So then (.02 x 100) = 2.41.  So would the answer be about 2 out of 31 people will die?

Comment: How did you get 1 out of 31?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fllowing R code to show the probabilities

```
p<-250000/320970000

dbinom(0,31,p)
dbinom(1,31,p)
dbinom(2,31,p)
dbinom(3,31,p)
```

The probability that none of the 31 people will die due to not exercising is 0.9761344. This is calculated from dbinom(0,31,p).

The probability that 1 of the 31 peeple will die due to not exercsiting of the 31 people is 0.02358768, this is caclcuated from dibinom(1,31,p).

You also can calculate 2, 3,4...to 31 people, the probability will be very small then.

```
x<-seq(0,31,by=1)
plot (x, dbinom(x,31, p), type = "l", ylab = "Probability",
main = "Probability of death due to not exerciseing")
```

[image]

Comment: You would have to make a number of strong assumptions in order to conclude that these death rates apply to the people in the class. What are these assumptions and why are they plausible?

Comment: Its more of a general, "statistically" this amount of people will die if I applied that every year 250,000 people die in the US (with a population of 370,970,000 people) to my class of 31 students.  My exposure to statistics is limited to "intermediate algebra" so I apologize if my logic in trying to create a statistic is way off.